# Image is not Scaling up on Hover

Tags: html, css

When I hover on the images it's not scaling up. I'm using `transform: scale()` to get that functionality.
I want to scale the image when I hover through them.

Somebody please help me to solve this.

```css
.row__posters {
  display: flex;
}

.row__poster {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  margin-right: 0.6em;
  transition: transform 450ms;
}

.row__poster :hover {
  transform: scale(1.08);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h2>Heading</h2>

  <div class="row__posters">

    <img class="row__poster" src="https://www.allaboutbirds.org/news/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/tricolored-heron-dorian-anderson-texas-124505431-1800-1280x853.jpg" alt="bird" /><img class="row__poster" src="https://www.allaboutbirds.org/news/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/tricolored-heron-dorian-anderson-texas-124505431-1800-1280x853.jpg"
      alt="bird" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the space before `:hover`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a little syntax mistake in css.

```
.row__poster :hover
```

should be

```
.row__poster:hover
```

```css
.row__posters {
  display: flex;
}

.row__poster {
  object-fit:contain;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  margin-right: 0.6em;
  transition: transform 450ms;
}

.row__poster:hover {
  transform: scale(1.08);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h2>Heading</h2>

  <div class="row__posters">

    <img class="row__poster" src="https://www.allaboutbirds.org/news/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/tricolored-heron-dorian-anderson-texas-124505431-1800-1280x853.jpg" alt="bird" /><img class="row__poster" src="https://www.allaboutbirds.org/news/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/tricolored-heron-dorian-anderson-texas-124505431-1800-1280x853.jpg"
      alt="bird" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're giving extra space for pseudo class `:hover` it was `row_poster :hover`
but fixing it will make `row_post:hover`

```css
.row__posters {
  display: flex;
}

.row__poster {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  margin-right: 0.6em;
  transition: transform 450ms;
}

.row__poster:hover {
  transform: scale(1.08);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h2>Heading</h2>

  <div class="row__posters">

    <img class="row__poster" src="https://www.allaboutbirds.org/news/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/tricolored-heron-dorian-anderson-texas-124505431-1800-1280x853.jpg" alt="bird" /><img class="row__poster" src="https://www.allaboutbirds.org/news/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/tricolored-heron-dorian-anderson-texas-124505431-1800-1280x853.jpg"
      alt="bird" />
  </div>
</div>
```